# Max number of attachements to chatter post

Tags: apex, chatter

For any chatter post, We can attach maximum of 10 attachements.
Salesforce documentation also says the same.

But How to set limit like 'Only 5 attachements can be added to chatter posts'.
I am not getting any way in documentations.

I am trying it with trigger on objects like contentVersion,ContentDocument etc.
But can we do it with configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above we can attach maximum of 10 files in the Chatter. We may not be able to limit the number of files through configuration. You can achieve it though writing a apex trigger on Feed Item/ Content Version/Document and can throw an error based on the number of attachments.

Comment: Okay SaiPraveen,Thank you